# remove Category and archive from wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog and in my blog page it says:

```
Archives
Category Archive for: ‘Blog’
```

At the very top inside a div called `inner`

```
<div id="feature">
    <div class="top_shadow"></div>
<div class="inner"><h1>Archives</h1>
<div id="introduce">Category Archive for: ‘Blog’</div>
</div>
```

I would like to completely get rid of this but do not see it anywhere inside of the settings. I am using the theme striking if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an display:none; on the CSS may solve your problem. What do you want to remove exactly?

If the superior  has an ID or a class, it would be as simple as #whateveriscalled {display:none;} or .whateveriscalled {display: none;}

Post exactly the div you want to remove.

Comment: The div inner and introduce are what I need to remove but feature would do the trick also I think but I am unsure if this is effective on all pages or not

Answer (score 1):

Look in your theme or child theme folder for a file called category.php

in the top of this file you'll probably be able to see these divs, if you can't do a search for the word feature. If you find them just comment them out or delete them. Make sure you save the code snippet that you remove somewhere so that you can put it back if it breaks.

If it's not in category.php, it may be in home.php

hope that helps!